# pine script strategy not showing any trades

Tags: pine-script

I have coded a strategy based on renko and daily ATR values. Pls note that Daily ATR value is taken as an input in the strategy from ATR indicator.
However, when I add the strategy to the chart, it is plotting the correct long and short signals from plotshape, but there is no list of trades or the automated long and short signals generated from the strategy.
The code is as follows:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Sahil_Trader

//@version=5
strategy("Renko Strat", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)


var firstflag = 0
var r_open = 0.0
var r_close = 0.0
var r_low = 0.0
var r_high = 0.0
var c_color = color.white
var c = 0
timeexit = not na(time("35", "1500-1534")) ? 1 : 0
timeentry = not na(time("10", "0900-0909")) ? 1 : 0

//GETTING THE DAILY ATR
ei = input(close, "ATR")
d_atr = 0.0
if na(ei)
    d_atr := d_atr[1]
else
    d_atr := ei

//CALCULATING BOX SIZE
box_size = 0.0
box_size := 0.07 * d_atr

//GETTING THE OPEN VALUE OF THE INDEX / SYMBOL

r1_open = 0.0
if timeentry
    r_open := open    //FIRST OPEN VALUE OF THE DAY
    r_close := close
//RENKO CALCULATIONS



size = 0.0
size := math.abs(close-open)
c := size >= box_size and close > open ? 1 : size >= box_size and close < open ? -1 : 0
if c == 1
    r_open := r_close[1]
    r_low := r_open
    r_close := r_open + box_size
    r_high := r_close
    c_color := color.green
if c == -1
    r_open := r_close[1]
    r_high := r_open
    r_close := r_open - box_size
    r_low := r_close
    c_color := color.red

if math.abs(close-open) <= box_size and firstflag == 1 and timeexit == 0
    
    r_open := r_open[1]
    r_close := r_close[1]
    r_high := r_high[1]
    r_low := r_low[1]
    c_color := c_color[1]

plotcandle(r_open, r_high, r_low, r_close, title='Title', color = c_color)


    


if timeexit
    c_color := color.yellow

call_entry = 0.0
put_entry = 0.0
callflag = 0
putflag = 0
call = c == 1 and c[1] == 0
put = c == -1 and c[1] == 0





longCondition = call
if (longCondition)
    callflag := 1
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.close("Short")

plotshape(call, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), location=location.bottom, size=size.small)
strategy.exit("long exit", "Long", profit = 4000 , loss = 1000)

shortCondition = put
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.close("Long")
strategy.exit("short exit", "Short", profit = 4000 , loss = 1000)
plotshape(put, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.new(color.red, 0), location=location.bottom, size=size.small)
```

Comment: Seems like a bug, try to copy ATR indicator logic inside your strategy as a workaround

Comment: Thanks but cant do that, as the strat has to work on 5 min TF and ATR on 1D TF, so as per my knowledge it wont be possible to do that

Comment: You can use security with ATR. attached example

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
strategy("Renko Strat", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

// ATR //
atrTimefame = input.timeframe("1D")
length = input.int(title="Length", defval=14, minval=1)
smoothing = input.string(title="Smoothing", defval="RMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA"])
ma_function(source, length) =>
    switch smoothing
        "RMA" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        => ta.wma(source, length)

atrValue = ma_function(ta.tr(true), length)
atrSecurity = request.security("", atrTimefame, atrValue)

// STRAT //
var firstflag = 0
var r_open = 0.0
var r_close = 0.0
var r_low = 0.0
var r_high = 0.0
var c_color = color.white
var c = 0
timeexit = not na(time("35", "1500-1534")) ? 1 : 0
timeentry = not na(time("10", "0900-0909")) ? 1 : 0

//GETTING THE DAILY ATR
//  ei = input(close, "ATR")
ei = atrSecurity

d_atr = 0.0
if na(ei)
    d_atr := d_atr[1]
else
    d_atr := ei

//CALCULATING BOX SIZE
box_size = 0.0
box_size := 0.07 * d_atr

//GETTING THE OPEN VALUE OF THE INDEX / SYMBOL

r1_open = 0.0
if timeentry
    r_open := open    //FIRST OPEN VALUE OF THE DAY
    r_close := close
//RENKO CALCULATIONS



size = 0.0
size := math.abs(close-open)
c := size >= box_size and close > open ? 1 : size >= box_size and close < open ? -1 : 0
if c == 1
    r_open := r_close[1]
    r_low := r_open
    r_close := r_open + box_size
    r_high := r_close
    c_color := color.green
if c == -1
    r_open := r_close[1]
    r_high := r_open
    r_close := r_open - box_size
    r_low := r_close
    c_color := color.red

if math.abs(close-open) <= box_size and firstflag == 1 and timeexit == 0
    
    r_open := r_open[1]
    r_close := r_close[1]
    r_high := r_high[1]
    r_low := r_low[1]
    c_color := c_color[1]

plotcandle(r_open, r_high, r_low, r_close, title='Title', color = c_color)


    


if timeexit
    c_color := color.yellow

call_entry = 0.0
put_entry = 0.0
callflag = 0
putflag = 0
call = c == 1 and c[1] == 0
put = c == -1 and c[1] == 0





longCondition = call
if (longCondition)
    callflag := 1
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.close("Short")

plotshape(call, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), location=location.bottom, size=size.small)
strategy.exit("long exit", "Long", profit = 4000 , loss = 1000)

shortCondition = put
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.close("Long")
strategy.exit("short exit", "Short", profit = 4000 , loss = 1000)
plotshape(put, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.new(color.red, 0), location=location.bottom, size=size.small)
```